# shared_buffers in greenplum are per-segment or for all segments?

Tags: database-administration, greenplum

As we have only one instance in postgres, but greenplum is a combination of many postgres instances sewn together.So setting up the shared buffer with "Alter system" will set the value for the master or all the segments?
For example setting a value of 125 MB for 8 segments will make shared_buffer 125*8= 1GB or will 125 MB be for all the segments

Comment: Keep in mind that you don't need a large shared_buffer setting. The typical workload ready much more data than you can fit into shared_buffers, or even the OS RAM. Hence you won't see large cache hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [shared_buffers configuration](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/latest/ref_guide/config_params/guc-list.html#shared_buffers) is a per-segment configuration. Setting a value of 125MB for 8 segments will allocate 1GB for all 8 segments. Here is a snippet from the documentation.

> Sets the amount of memory a Greenplum Database segment instance uses for shared memory buffers. This setting must be at least 128KB and at least 16KB times max_connections.
>
> ...
>
> Each Greenplum Database segment instance calculates and attempts to allocate certain amount of shared memory based on the segment configuration.